# Closing the window tab

Tags: javascript, browser

I want to load a webpage http://localhost/12.13.12.56.

I'm returning this content which should close this tab:

```
<html><head>
<script>
 window.load=function(){ window.close();}
</script> 
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

But the Google Chrome console is showing this error:

> Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.

**After loading of this url I want to close it automatically. How can I do that?**

Answer (score 0):

It means, The `window.close()` function will work only for the tabs, Which is opened by your script **OR** opened from your page.

something like,

```
var w = window.open('location','_blank');
w.close();
```

Attempting to close tab while loading it is a bad idea. Why you want to do that?

Comment: I'll click ipaddress in google sheet which will open this url 
 http://localhost/12.13.12.56 will call a local webserver, which will automatically start the tightvnc viewer withthis ip address. Just for automation